# Form Submit in Laravel Results to 404

Tags: forms, laravel-5, post, routes

I installed Laravel then copied index.php from public to root and changes some lines in index.php. I also copied htaccess. Now I tried creating a route like so below

I tried using {{ url('signin') }} and {{ route('signin') }} but to no avail

```
        <form action="{{ route('signin') }}" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div>Email: <input type="text" name="username" class="userName textboxes push-right-33"></div>

            <div>Password: <input type="password" name="password" class="password textboxes"></div></br>

            <div class="fpassword-section">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password</a>
            </div>

            <div class="links">
                <input type="submit" class="button button-signin signin" value="Sign In">
            </div>
        </form>
```

and my route will be

```
Route::any('/signin', 'LoginContoller@authenticateUser')->name('signin');
```

and my controller be like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class LoginContoller extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        return view('pages.login');

    }

    public function authenticateUser(Request $var){
        echo "string";
    }
}
```

Authenticate user does not return anything instead of 404

Comment: "copied index.php from public to root and changes some lines in index.php" but you posted other code. I wonder you don't get a 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong URL. You don't need to pass the public in URL. it's base URL.

```
<form action="{{ url('signin') }}" method="POST">
```

Or if you want to do with route then.

```
<form action="{{ route('signin') }}" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>

//route.php define that route as name.
Route::post('/signin', 'LoginContoller@authenticateUser')->name('signin');
```

Comment: Add in your form `{{ csrf_field() }}` under form tag.

Comment: Also the same. 419 unknown status

Comment: Can you edit your question and show me the form. Because if you get 419 error it means csrf error.

Comment: which version of laravel are you using? And don't you know about laravel `Auth` . Why you are making manual login? use Auth login.

Comment: Try like this `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: 5.8 Sir. For testing purposes.

Comment: Sorry I was using 6.0 laravel